# Is any Dependency Injection implemented by default in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I was recently asked in an interview which type of DI is implemented by default in .Net Core. Can anyone please tell me if any DI is actually implemented by default at all or not? I couldn't find the exact answer to the question anywhere.

Comment: It's 95% likely they meant ServiceProvider/ServiceCollection, but they asked the question badly. They meant "What sort of DI container does an ASP.NET Core application use by default?" The way it was asked, I would have asked "Are you referring to..." and answered that. Then if that wasn't what they meant they could clarify. Answering in-depth about what DI is and isn't might be okay, but they're really asking a simpler question. They just didn't ask it well.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, it is important to understand the difference between DI and DI containers. *DI* - is a design pattern and *DI container* - is a tool, framework, or package that helps you to implement DI as a pattern(even though you still can implement it without any external tools). So, I assume, you were asked whether *DI container* is a part of the .NET Core by default.

DI container is a part of the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) or [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) packages. The question you were asked is rather controversial. This package may come as part of the template you use to create your .NET project from Visual Studio or from CLI. For example, *ASP.NET* or *Worker Service* templates - have a DI container as part of the template, yet the Console App does not. From my point of view, there is no "default", it's you who choose whether you want to use these packages or not, or if you want to use DI as a design pattern at all.

I know it can be slightly confusing. And it is confusing because .NET is a *framework*, which means it can dictate you the way you build your projects, it has a lot of embedded into its ecosystem approaches people usually follow. But the point is - you don't have to, you can use C# purely and not use all things people tend to call "default", it's optional, but they are built to enhance development velocity

Comment: "DI - is a design pattern". [Mark](https://blog.ploeh.dk/) and I rather say that "Dependency Injection is a set of software design principles and patterns that enables you to develop loosely coupled code".